# Swift: Make text bold in message of UIAlertContorller

Tags: ios, swift

I am making an iOS version of an Android app. I want to make the string I am passing through to be bold. In the other app it is done by adding html as shown below. I tried this and it did not work. Is there a way of implementing this or work around possibly?

Side note: showPrompt is a switch I made for UIAlertController functions.

Thanks,

```
func systemUpdateCheck(oCurVer: String){    

    showPrompt("A new version has been released,<b>v." + oCurVer + "<b>.<br/>Tap OK to download and install the new version", sType: "alert", sJSResp: "")
}
```

Answer (score 6):

try this

> ```
> let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Message", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name:".SFUIText-BoldItalic", size: 12)!])
> let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
> alert.setValue(attributedText, forKey: "attributedMessage")
> let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: LocalizedString("Ok"), style: .default)
> alert.addAction(okAction)
> present(alert, animated: true)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question was asked a long time ago and we are now on iOS 16 & Swift 5.5 but I found this workable solution:-

```
let message = "This is a message with bold text"
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: message)
let range = (message as NSString).range(of: "bold text")
attributedString.addAttribute(.font, value: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17), range: range)

let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert Title", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
alert.setValue(attributedString, forKey: "attributedMessage")
let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
alert.addAction(action)
present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's no public API to alter the text appearance in a UIAlertController.

The new `UIAlertController` is just a `UIViewController` subclass. You could create a custom `UIViewController` subclass and obtain a much more fine-grained control over its appearance and behaviour.